# Error in react build: native code is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am getting a very strange error in my react build that just breaks everything and all I see is a blank page.

This is the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: function call() { [native code] } is not a function!
    at 128.4c993361.chunk.js:1
    at B (128.4c993361.chunk.js:1)
    at e (128.4c993361.chunk.js:1)
    at 128.4c993361.chunk.js:1
    at Object.<anonymous> (128.4c993361.chunk.js:1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (128.4c993361.chunk.js:1)
    at l ((index):1)
    at Module.701 (main.af07ead1.chunk.js:1)
    at l ((index):1)
    at Module.827 (main.af07ead1.chunk.js:1)
(anonymous) @ 128.4c993361.chunk.js:1
B @ 128.4c993361.chunk.js:1
e @ 128.4c993361.chunk.js:1
(anonymous) @ 128.4c993361.chunk.js:1
(anonymous) @ 128.4c993361.chunk.js:1
(anonymous) @ 128.4c993361.chunk.js:1
l @ (index):1
701 @ main.af07ead1.chunk.js:1
l @ (index):1
827 @ main.af07ead1.chunk.js:1
l @ (index):1
826 @ main.af07ead1.chunk.js:1
l @ (index):1
b @ (index):1
e @ (index):1
(anonymous) @ main.af07ead1.chunk.js:1
```

Usually, if it's an error in my code react just displays a message with a link with the error details but in this case, it seems that it's an error from the build.

I tried to re-build the project and after that I removed the `node_modules` folder and ran `npm install` again but I keep getting that error.

I can't see this error when I run the project locally and it works perfectly fine when I use `npm start`.

I've build the project on my machine, locally and I'm getting the same error with my local build.

Is there any way to debug it so I can see what exactly is causing this error?

Comment: It's difficult to say what is causing this without seeing your code, it looks like you may be referencing a function as if it were a property instead of a function (ie missing the parenthesis)

Comment: I don't know, but I agree with the above @ThatCoderGuy and only wish to add that you could be doing something like f.toString() of a function f, which in certain circumstances will return something similar to your error (as opposed to the function with its body as it will do in other cases). For you it's like something like Function.call.toString() happened which is a bit bizarre

Comment: Perhaps something akin to (Function.call + "")() is happening

Comment: Yes, it's possible but why am I seeing this only when I build the project? Why isn't this error thrown when I use the development server?

Comment: I just fixed the problem. It was because of firebase, apparently, I've reached some limit and it was throwing an error.